# Functional equation $f(\frac xy)=f(x)/f(y)$ and $f'(1)=2$

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

Find $f(x)$ that verifies:

- $f\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)=\dfrac{f(x)}{f(y)}$ for all $x,y$ such that
- $f(y)\neq 0$
- $f'(1)=2$

How to solve such a question ?

Comment: Edit: I reformulated your condition. You cannot have $f(y)\neq 0$ for all $y$, instead I stated that the functional equation is verified whenever $f(y)\neq 0$.

Comment: @zwim Well it is given in the question that f(y)≠0 for all y

Comment: yep, but the problem with that is $x\mapsto x^2$ is no solution anymore... Hence my change.

Comment: The answer given in my book is f(x)=1+x^2

Answer (score 2):

As $f'(1)$ exists and is non-zero, there is a neighbourhood of $1$ where $f$ is not identically zero. In particlar, there exists $a>0$  with $f(a)\ne 0$. Then 
$$\tag1 f(1)=f(\tfrac aa)=\frac{f(a)}{f(a)}=1.$$
If $x>0$ and $f(\sqrt x)\ne 0$, we see from $f(\sqrt x)=f(\frac x{\sqrt x})=\frac{f(x)}{f(\sqrt x)}$ that 
$$\tag{$\star$} f(x)>0\qquad \text{if }x\ge0\text{ and }f(\sqrt x)\ne0. $$

By continuity at $x=1$, we have $f(x)>0$ in a neighbourhood of $1$. Let $u=\sup\{\,x<1\mid f(x)\le 0\,\}$ and $v=\inf\{\,x>1\mid f(x)\le 0\,\}$. If $v<\infty$, then certainly $v>1$ and so for $v\le x< v^2$, we have  $1<\sqrt x< v$ and from $(\star)$ conclude that $f(x)>0$, contradicting the definition of $v$. Similarly, if $u>0$, we find $f(x)>0$ for $u^2<x\le u$, contradicting the definition of $u$. We conclude that $v=+\infty$ and $u\le 0$, i.e., 
$$ f(x)>0\qquad\text{for }x>0. $$

Define $g(x)=\ln f(e^x)$ (allowed as $f(e^x)>0$). Then $g(x+y-y)=g(x+y)-g(y)$, and so
$$\tag2 g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$$
for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$. As $f$ is differentiable at $1$, it must in particular be continuous there, and that means that $g$ is continuous at $0$. It is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation) that the only solutions to $(2)$ that are continuous at at least one point are of the form $$g(x)=cx$$
for some constant $c$.
It follows that, 
$$ f(x)=f(e^{\ln x})=e^{g(\ln x)}=e^{c\ln x}=x^c\qquad\text{for x>0}.$$

By taking derivatives at $x=1$, we find $c=2$, i.e., 
$$\tag3 f(x)=x^2\qquad\text{for x>0}.$$

From 
$$ f(0)= f(\tfrac 02)=\frac{f(0)}{f(2)}=\frac{f(0)}4$$
we find
$$\tag4 f(0)=0.$$
Assume there exists $b<0$ with $f(b)\ne 0$.
Then 
$$ \tag5f(x)=f(\tfrac{bx}b)=\frac{f(bx)}{f(b)}=\frac{b^2x^2}{f(b)}\qquad\text{for x<0}.$$
In particular $f(-1)=\frac{b^2}{f(b)}\ne 0$ and from 
$$ f(-1)=f(\tfrac1{-1})=\frac{f(1)}{f(-1)}$$
we obtain
$$ f(-1)=\pm 1.$$
Plugging this into $(5)$ we find that either
$$\tag{6a}f(x)=x^2 \qquad\text{for x<0}$$
or
$$\tag{6b}f(x)=-x^2 \qquad\text{for x<0}.$$
Together with $(3)$ and $(4)$, we find that the only candidate solutions are
$$\fbox{$ f(x)=x^2$}$$
and
$$ \fbox{$f(x)=|x|\cdot x=\begin{cases}x^2&x\ge 0\\-x^2&x\le 0\end{cases}$}$$
as well as the solution where no $b<0$ with $f(b)\ne 0$ exists, i.e., 
$$ \fbox{$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&x\ge 0\\0&x\le 0\end{cases}$}.$$
One immediately verifies that indeed all three candidates have the desired properties.

**Remark:** As the results show, it turns out that $f$ must be differentiable, even though we were given only differentiability at $x=1$ and did not even have to assume continuity at any other point.

Comment: Note, I think we can take $a=1$ at the very beginning since If $f(1)=0$ then for all $x$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$ we would get $f(1)=0=\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)}=1$ which is a contradiction. So either $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ but in this case $f'(1)=2$ is not possible, either $f(1)\neq 0$.

Comment: The answer given in my book is f(x)=1+x²

Comment: @zwim Yes, that's also possible. $f$ cannot be identically zero (you: on all of $\Bbb R$; I: in a neighbourhood of $1$) becasue that would make $f'(1)=0$. Hence $f(a)\ne 0$ for some $a$ (you: $\in\Bbb R$; I: $\approx 1$) and $f(1)=\frac{f(a)}{f(a)}=1$.

Comment: @user744725 Obviously, with $f(x)=1+x^2$ we have $5=f(2)=f(\frac42)$ but $\frac{f(4)}{f(2)}=\frac{17}5\ne 5$.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd start by thinking of potential families of functions that would satisfy the condition.

I know that $f(x) = x^k$ would satisfy the condition $f(x/y) = f(x)/f(y)$.

After that I just need to find one such $k$ and I am done.

To do this, I will differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ to get:

$\frac{1}{y}f'(x/y) = f'(x)/f(y)$.

Substitute $x = 1$:

$\frac{1}{y}f'(1/y)f(y) = 2$.

Next use $f(y) = y^k$.

We have $k=2$.

By subsitution $f(x) = x^2$ solves this.

A trial an error type effort with $f(x)=x^k$ for small $k$ would work too.

Answer (score 0):

If
$f(\dfrac{x}{y})
=\dfrac{f(x)}{f(y)}
$
then
$f(\dfrac{x}{y})f(y)
=f(x)
$.

Setting
$\dfrac{x}{y} = z$,
this is
$f(z)f(y) = f(zy)$.

Differentiable solutions to this are
$f(x)
=x^a
$
with 
$ a
=f'(1)
$
(shown below).

Since $f'(1) = 2$,
we have
$a = 2$
so
$f(x) = x^2$.

As a check,
$(x^2)' = 2x$
so
$(x^2)'(1) = 2$.

Show:

If
$f(z)f(y) = f(zy)$,
then,
setting $z=1$,
$f(1) = 1$
and
$f(x+h)
=f(x(1+h/x))
=f(x)f(1+h/x)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
f(x+h)-f(x)
&=f(x)f(1+h/x)-f(x)\\
&=f(x)(f(1+h/x)-1)\\
&=f(x)(f(1+h/x)-f(1))\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
&=f(x)\dfrac{f(1+h/x)-f(1)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\dfrac{f(1+h/x)-f(1)}{h/x}\\
\end{array}
$

Letting $h \to 0$,
$f'(x)
=\dfrac{f(x)}{x}f'(1)
$
or
$\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
=\dfrac{f'(1)}{x}
$.

Integrating,
$\ln(f(x))
=f'(1)\ln(x)+c
=\ln(Cx^{f'(1)})
$
so
$f(x)
=Cx^{f'(1)}
$.

Setting $x=1$,
$1 = f(1)
=C
$
so
$f(x)
=x^{f'(1)}
$.